# How do I dynamically resize my tkinter buttons using the grid system?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm trying to make a basic calculator and am using the grid system instead of packing. However, when I add weight to the rows and the columns, the buttons do not expand they merely just end up shifting slightly.

```
`
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("310x125")

opNum = ""
def printHello(num):
    global opNum
    opNum = opNum + num
    print(opNum)

def printResult():
    global opNum
    global entResult
    calcResult = eval(opNum)
    calcResult = str(calcResult)
    opNum = ""
    entResult  = ttk.Label(keyPad, text = calcResult, ).grid(column = 3 , row = 0, sticky = "NSEW")
    calcResult = ""


    
keyPad = ttk.Frame(root)
keyPad.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


Grid.rowconfigure(keyPad, (0,1,2,3,4), weight = 2,)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, (0,1,2,3,4) ,weight = 2, )


entResult = ttk.Label(keyPad, text ="Enter", borderwidth = 1).grid(column = 3 , row = 0, sticky = "NSEW")
b0  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "0" , command  = lambda: printHello("0")).grid(column = 0, row = 4 , columnspan = 2, sticky  = "NSEW")
b1  = ttk.Button(keyPad,  text = "1" , command  = lambda:printHello("1") ).grid(column = 0 , row =3, sticky  = "NSEW")
b4  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "4" , command  = lambda:printHello("4") ).grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky  = "NSEW")
b7  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "7" , command  = lambda:printHello("7")  ).grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky  = "NSEW")
b2  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "2" , command  = lambda:printHello("2")  ).grid(column = 1 , row = 3, sticky  = "NSEW")
b5  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "5" , command  = lambda:printHello("5")  ).grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky  = "NSEW")
b8  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "8" , command  = lambda:printHello("8")  ).grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky  = "NSEW")
b3  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "3" , command  = lambda:printHello("3")  ).grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky  = "NSEW")
b6  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "6" , command  = lambda:printHello("6")  ).grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky  = "NSEW")
b9  = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "9" , command  = lambda:printHello("9")  ).grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky  = "NSEW")

b_equals = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "=", command = printResult).grid(column = 2, row = 4, sticky = "NSEW")
b_plus = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "+", command = lambda:printHello("+")).grid(column = 3, row = 1, sticky = "NSEW")
b_minus = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "-", command = lambda:printHello("-")).grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = "NSEW")
b_mult = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "*", command = lambda:printHello("*")).grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = "NSEW")
b_div = ttk.Button(keyPad, text = "/", command = lambda:printHello("/")).grid(column = 3, row = 4, sticky = "NSEW")





    


root.mainloop()

`
```

I have tried adding NEWS stickies but I encounter the issue noted above. Also I have tried configuring the weight of the rows and columns but all these configurations have left me here. I've also looked on numerous websites on guides how to dynamically resizing but still they do not work. It might be worth mentioning that I am new to tkinter so there might just be a basic concept I am missing

Comment: Add `sticky="news"` to `keyPad.grid(...)` and also `root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` with `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Comment: This solved it bro. tysm